# Similar way to PHP Sessions in Zoho Creator

Tags: php, zoho

A short tutorial in W3schools about PHP Sessions writes the following:

> When you work with an application, you open it, do some changes, and then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who you are or what you do, because the HTTP address doesn't maintain state.
>   Session variables solve this problem by storing user information to be used across multiple pages (e.g. username, favorite color, etc). By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.
>   So; Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

I would like to ask you if there is something similar in Zoho Creator. The reason why I am asking is because I have an application with 3 pages (each page has an embedded form). Each page redirects to the other (1st Page -> 2nd Page -> 3rd Page) and passes data through them via openurl. The final result is an HTML Page with the data of these 3 Pages (they have a unique ID).

Let's say that I am in the second page and for some reason (electricity blackout, do another job and close the browser) I want to escape from the application and the next time to continue from the same point, is there any way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you next way
On first page generate unique session Id for the user and pass this id as a parameter to next page in URL. You can crypt in this id pointer to record from first form for example..